# What is the difference between google cloud datalab and google cloud ai platform notebooks?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I'm looking into the best way to set up an end-to-end machine learning pipeline, and evaluating the data exploration component options.

I'm trying to figure out the difference between google cloud datalab, and google cloud ai platform notebooks. They both seem to offer similar functionality, so not sure why they both exist, or whether one is a new iteration of the other.

If they are different, what is the benefit of one over the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Google Cloud AI Platform Notebooks is effectively the upgraded version of Google Cloud Datalab and gives you benefits like being able to use the notebook directly in your browser without having to setup an ssh tunnel first (which datalab forces you to do).

If you're creating a new notebook, you 100% want to go with AI Platform Notebooks

*(Also, Datalab is now deprecated)*

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the *End-to-End Machine Learning with TensorFlow on GCP* course on Coursera ([link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/end-to-end-ml-tensorflow-gcp)) -

> AI Platform Notebooks is the next generation of hosted notebook on GCP, and has replaced Cloud Datalab.