# What is difference between AI Notebook and Cloud Datalab in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have searched for an answer to this question and this question is duplicate but I need clarification as I looked at two different places and answers are a bit opposite.

The following Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58329351/9146820) mentions that *Google Cloud AI Platform Notebooks is an upgraded version of Google Cloud Datalab*. On the following Quora [page](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Google-Cloud-Datalab-and-Jupyter-notebooks), one of the architects mentions that *Cloud Datalab is built on top of Jypyter Notebook*.

Cloud Datalab is adding a new network of its own. AI Notebooks remains within an existing network. With the current setup of my environment, I do not want to add overhead of maintaining extra network and security to watch over, and so AI Notebooks is the immediate solution. But I would also want to understand the benefits that Cloud Datalab provides.

- Between AI Notebook and Cloud Datalab, which should be used and in which
  scenario?
- Is Cloud Datalab also providing pre-installed packages of Python,
  Tensorflow or R environment like AI Notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

> Between AI Notebook and Cloud Datalab, which should be used and in
> which scenario?

You should use AI notebooks on new projects in any case since Cloud Datalab would be deprecated sooner than later.

> Is Cloud Datalab also providing pre-installed packages of Python,
> Tensorflow or R environment like AI Notebooks?

[Yes it does.](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/concepts/key-concepts#included_libraries)

*Summary of the differences between the two products.*

1. DataLab

   - Custom UI that is not compatible with latest JupyterLab extensions.
   - Using old PyDatalab SDK since when DataLab was released there were no official SDK available for many of GCP services.
   - No major changes on RoadMap.
   - Requires SSH with port mapping to use
2. Notebooks:

   - Using JupyterLab UI.
   - Using official SDKs (like BigQuery Python SDK), therefore better integration.
   - Since UI (JupyterLab) is community driven releasing new changes rapidly.
   - Access to UI is simple, no SSH, no CLI usage is required.
   - Notebooks API
   - Terraform [support](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/notebooks_instance)
   - Client libraries ([Python](https://googleapis.dev/python/notebooks/latest/index.html), [Java](https://github.com/googleapis/java-notebooks), [NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/notebooks?activeTab=readme)) to manage Notebooks