# I can not use Google Cloud Translation API in datalab

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-translation-api

I am a newbie of GCP.
I tried to play with GCP Translation API in GCP Datalab.
I setup as procedure in [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup?hl=en_US)(by directly input command in Datalab's Notebook)

The last lines showed that the installation was successful. But it has some red portion indicated dependencies issue.
Later I exported path of my service key to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
Later I checked auth and found no error.

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

Later I added sample code from [GCP Quick start](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/quickstart?hl=en_US) and found error.

```
ContextualVersionConflict: (google-cloud-core 0.28.1 (/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('google-cloud-core<2.0dev,>=1.1.0'), set(['google-cloud-translate']))
```

[gcp_translation_api_error0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqocc.png)
[gcp_translation_api_error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8bME.png)

Please help me how to solve this dependency issue. Note that I selected Python2 in Datalab's Notebook.

Comment: You happen to mention to be using python2 within your notebook settings. Unfortunately,  [Python2 version is deprecated](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/index.html#deprecated-python-versions) so please bear in mind that the last version of this library compatible with Python 2.7 is google-cloud-translate==2.0.1. Are you installing "Basic client libraries" or "Advanced client libraries"?

Comment: Moreover, it is recommended to use AI notebooks since they are up to date and they use official SDKs (like BigQuery Python SDK). Could you migrate to Jupyter Notebooks?
Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720589/what-is-difference-between-ai-notebook-and-cloud-datalab-in-gcp

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.  I will try again with python3 in Datalab. AI Notebook is also my new try.